# Augment category detail with product information

Tags: php, arrays, json, magento

I currently have a piece of code that puts together data about all of the categories in Magento.  I would like to add product details, including but not limited to:

- price
- sku
- image url

I'm having trouble adding those attributes to the response

```
<?php

require_once('../app/Mage.php'); //Path to Magento
umask(0);
Mage::app();   
function getCategoryTree($recursionLevel, $storeId = 1)
{
    $parent = Mage::app()->getStore()->getRootCategoryId();    
    $tree = Mage::getResourceModel('catalog/category_tree');

    $nodes = $tree->loadNode($parent)
        ->loadChildren($recursionLevel)
        ->getChildren();
    $tree->addCollectionData(null, false, $parent);


    $categoryTreeData = array();
    foreach ($nodes as $node) {
        $categoryTreeData[$node->getData('entity_id')] = getNodeChildrenData($node);
    }

    return $categoryTreeData;
}

function getNodeChildrenData(Varien_Data_Tree_Node $node)
{
    $data = array(
        'title' => $node->getName(),
        'url'   => $node->getData('url_key'),
        'price'   => $node->getPrice(),
    );

    foreach ($node->getChildren() as $childNode) {
        if (!array_key_exists('children', $data)) {
            $data['children'] = array();
        }

        $data['children'][$childNode->getData('entity_id')] = getNodeChildrenData($childNode);
    }
    return $data;
}

print_r(json_encode(getCategoryTree(100)));

?>
```

Comment: A category doesn't have a price. What do you really want to do?

Comment: I don't even see a product model in this code - that's really not a good start! Try some things, do some reading about the `catalog/product` model.

Answer (score 1):

You can easily bring in information about products, but you'll need to load product collections along the way.  So far you're dealing with only category models (as mentioned in the comments) which don't contain any product data.

To load the set of products associated with a category, use:

```
<?php
...
$products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect({attribute})
    ->addCategoryFilter($category)
    ->load();
```

`$category` should be a category object and `$products` is a collection of products that you can loop through.  For each product attribute that you are interested in, add an `addAttributeToSelect()` entry with the name of the attribute in the pares. You can then get product details by writing things like:

```
<?php
...
foreach($products as $product) {
    $price = $product->getPrice();
}
```

Comment: Hi evan. You may improve your answer and suggest to add addAttributeToSelect () to avoid loading all attributes and only load the necessary ones. The colllection may be huge so performance may become an issue.